# using spread venom for a person?

Tags: meaning

what you say when someone finally does something he wanted for a long time and by that bothers others. Is it correct to say: he did it, he finally spread his venom?

Student A and professor B our somehow opponents. A has an idea and wants to make it public which will destroy B. All of students try to prevent him from doing it for Professor sake. But A finally does it. Now others talk about A and they say: he eventually did it.
Is it common to add?: He finally poured/spit his venom/poison

Comment: Please edit your question to give a concrete example. The phrase is not one I've heard, but it might perhaps be appropriate in some particular circumstance.

Comment: "he spread venom in his words"?

Comment: 'Spit venom' is colloquial, despite the fact that snakes squirt venom through their teeth when they bite. They don't actually spit it.

Comment: You know, I need to know what an English speaker says in this situation:

Comment: Not everything is already in existence. Thank goodness for that. What's wrong with spread venom?  His venom can be an image for his nastiness, his meanness, his irritability. That said, I might be more likely to write: He finally started spreading his venom around [the community, the neighborhood, through the company. etc.]

Comment: Normally "venom" is used in metaphors which refer to spreading malicious talk.  Your use would likely not be comprehended.

Comment: @Saideh "...in this situation." **What** situation? Please be specific.

Comment: You know, I need to know what an English speaker says in this situation: when someone does something that he insisted on it very much, but the others think it is wrong and malicious to do it. In this situation those other say: He finally did it.In my language we say  He split his venom or poison , what would an English speaker say?

Comment: You need to **describe the situation.** Give an actual, concrete example. Also, please [edit it into your question](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/435672/edit).

Comment: @Lambie "he spread his venom" can be found in many instances in googlebooks search.  Answer worthy?

Comment: But, once again, "venom" is generally used to mean "malicious gossip", or something of that nature.  Simply "bothering others" through his actions is not "venom".

Comment: I think this may be a term that has a language barrier issue, there is not a specific term that refers to someone finally doing something malicious in English that i have ever heard of am aware of. If someone always wanted to vandalize someone else's property i would simply say he actually or finally vandalized Steve car, then i could follow it up with what a jerk, or i hope he gets in trouble etc

Comment: @ibf I have no problem with it. Even when stuff isn't it books, there are many, many reasons for that. Anyway, here spread means distribute to others; not just let it out. Do you mean let it out in anger? Or spread it around? English speakers, listen up: "He was always gossiping about everyone, spreading his venom every time he opened his mouth." It's perfectly literary....

Comment: Oh boy, I just realized: to spew his venom. SPEW, folks. :) spread is OK, but the idea of it spewing out, is also often used.

Comment: @Nate W as I understand in English people do not use the expression that I said?

Comment: It is not "an expression". But it can be a way to express an idea. Spew is most often collocated with it, for anger and nastiness. To spew venom, to spew hatred, to spew nonsense.

Comment: to spread, say, spew ... IMHO it is seen and heard in contemporary America.

Comment: @Lambie thank you so much.  I checked and as you said spew venom is more common than spread venom.

Comment: I agree with what @Lambie said regarding spew, and his example is a good one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, one can spread his **venom** though in the states one hears spewing more often.  But continue reading:

> something resembling or suggesting poison in its effect; spite;
>   malice: 'the venom of jealousy'. [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/venom?s=t)

or

> spiteful; malignant: 'a venomous attack; a venomous tongue'. (same
>   reference)

see use of spewing and even bloviating venom at same reference!  Also a googlebooks search of "he spread his venom" reveals frequent usage in Am lit.

Comment: i may get a venomous bite(s) with my answer ... if so allow me to gracefully head to the ER (withdraw answer. lol)

Comment: the 'jury' is still out on my answer ... did my best.

Comment: I am not a native speaker and sometimes it is difficult to grasp some meaning , would you please explain the the tow last comment of yours?

Comment: this is a community forum ... questions and answers are 'analyzed' by its members and may receive good or bad feedback.

Comment: now I get it :)   I marked your answer as a useful one. thanks